# How to create a collapsing logo div above a fixed bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I need to create a div with full page width that can hold a background image and a logo image that decreases in size as you scroll down. I've tried a few attempts but can't seem to crack it. A perfect example of this in execution can be found here: http://www.starwars.com/

EDIT:
Manages to get something working now but as I scroll back up, the navbar animates down the page briefly, showing a layer beneath in the z-index that it wouldn't show when it reaches the bottom.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var objectSelect = $("#contentcollapse");
var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
if (scroll > 400) {
    $(".navscroll").addClass("navstick");
    $(".navstick").removeClass("navscroll");
} else {
    $(".navstick").addClass("navscroll");
    $(".navscroll").removeClass("navstick");
}
});
```

Is there a reason why there would be some sort of animated transition between the changing of the classes?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you with your problem

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/tomdurkin/pen/nvAjd

```
    $(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if
  ($(document).scrollTop() > 100){
      $("header").addClass("shrink");
        updateSliderMargin();
    }
    else
    {
        $("header").removeClass("shrink");
        updateSliderMargin();
    }
});
```

Here is a codepen that does what you want (this is **not** my code but Tom Durkin's )
The question has already been adressed both on SO and on google. You should consider marking it as duplicate...

Comment: It's getting it to show up above a bootstrap navigation bar that is fixed which is making it harder

Comment: @Joel You have to care about where the fixed navigation bar start and adjust according to it. If you don't give us your code, we cannot help you more than that (generic) answer. If your problem is to get it to show ABOVE the fixed header, use `z-index:100`

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow so you'll have to forgive my novice attempt at asking the question. How would you go about creating something like the example shown in the link in my question? Will get the code on here soon

Comment: Maybe i am too noob at understanding question as well, but i don't see the difference between the example and your question, or why you would have trouble with positioning the header compared to it...
Notify me when you post the code and i'll take a closer look (don't know if i will have an answer tho!)

Comment: Here is an example of what I have, I just need to get the content div to stick when it reaches 100px from the top http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/header-effect/basic-demo/index.html